# Finding the orthogonal complement of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an orthonormal base, and want to find its orthogonal complement, how do I proceed? Is there a quick way because of the the orthonormal basis?

My ON-base:
$$ 
c1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ -2\\  2\\ 0\end{pmatrix},
c2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\  1\\  1\\ 1\end{pmatrix},
c3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 3\\ -3\\ -3\\ 3\end{pmatrix}
$$

I forgot to write down the normalisation for you, its 1/3,1/2,1/6, for c1, c2,c3.

Comment: Your basis is not orthonormal. "Orthogonal" and "orthonormal" are two different things.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to att the "normalisation factor", added them now

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

One way is to form the matrix $A = [c_1 | c_2 | c_3 ]$ and solve the systems $A^T \vec{x} = \vec{0}$

Comment: Is the nullspace orthogonal to my ON-basis?

Comment: @TeaClub *orthogonal* means zero product, i.e. $x \perp y$ if and only if $x^T y = 0$.

Comment: You want to solve $yA^T=0$ instead.

Comment: @Jack thanks fixed

Answer (score 0):

Find a $\vec{c}_{4}$ so that the set of all four vectors is linearly independent, and then use the Gram-Schmidt process.

Answer (score 0):

It is not orthogonal complement to some basis but orthogonal complement of some *subspace*.

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$. The orthogonal complement of $S$, denoted $S^\perp$, is the subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$ that contains the vectors orthogonal to all the vectors in $S$.

If the subspace is described as the range of a matrix: $S = \{Ax : x \in \mathbf{R}^n \}$, then the orthogonal complement is the set of vectors orthogonal to the rows of $A$, which is the *nullspace* of $A^T$.

When looking for $null(A^T)$, essentially one needs to solve the linear equation
$$
y^TA^T=0.
$$

I don't think orthogonality of columns of $A$ would give any short cut for solving it.

Comment: Yeah, i found the null(A^T), its 2 vectors, with 5 elements in each. Do they span R5? Can i make them span R5 somehow?